# Why iterator from unordered_set is read-only?

Tags: c++, const-iterator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>


using namespace std;
struct Car {
    int plate;
    int fuel = 0;
    Car(int plate) : plate(plate) { }

    inline bool operator==(const Car& car) const {
        return car.plate== this->plate;
    }
};

namespace std{
template<>
struct hash<Car> {
    size_t operator()(const Car& x) const {
        return x.plate;
    }
};
}

int main(){
    unordered_set<Car> cars;
    Car c1(123);
    cars.insert(c1);
    auto it = cars.begin();
    while (it != cars.end()){
        // ERROR: assignment of member 'Car::fuel' in read-only object
        it->fuel = 1;
        ++it;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the above example, how can I change the fuel of the car? Using `vector` doesn't raise this problem.

Comment: @nrussell i need to modify the object attribute, so I need to create a `struct` to simulate the problem, if it is `int`, i can't simulate the problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you need an `unordered_set`?  You should not be(can't) modify the key in "sorted" containers.

Comment: std::unordered_set uses a hash table to store the elements. Each element is stored based on a key returned by a hash function. Now if you change the value of an element, you'll have an element stored in the hash table which doesn't (possibly) correspond to the key returned by the hash function on the new value.

Comment: Just realize it is duplicate question, changing to `unordered_map` is the best possible solution for now. @NathanOliver, I need set property because of the uniqueness check.

Comment: @Yeo Okay.  `unordered_map` should be what you need then.